# TypeError items.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, web-frontend

As a beginner to React JS, I keep getting TypeErrors when I run my App.js. Could you please advise me what I can do to resolve this issue?

I am now working on the frontend of a program that allows customers to pre-order food and beverages online.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/items").then((response) => setItems(response.data));
  }, []);

  const addToCart = (item) => {
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  };

  const removeFromCart = (item) => {
    setCart(cart.filter((i) => i.id !== item.id));
  };

  const submitOrder = () => {
    const order = {
      customer: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        phoneNumber: "",
      },
      items: cart,
      paymentMethod: "CASH",
    };
    axios.post("/api/orders", order).then(() => setCart([]));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Food and Beverage Items</h1>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name} ({item.price}){" "}
            <button onClick={() => addToCart(item)}>Add to Cart</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <h1>Cart</h1>
      <ul>
        {cart.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name} ({item.price}){" "}
            <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(item)}>Remove</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={submitOrder}>Submit Order</button>
    </div>
  )}
    
export default App;
```

Comment: check your `response.data`. It seems that it's not an array

Answer (score -1):

All seems to be correct, except for a missing closing parenthesis at the end of the component definition.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/items").then((response) => setItems(response.data));
  }, []);

  const addToCart = (item) => {
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  };

  const removeFromCart = (item) => {
    setCart(cart.filter((i) => i.id !== item.id));
  };

  const submitOrder = () => {
    const order = {
      customer: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        phoneNumber: "",
      },
      items: cart,
      paymentMethod: "CASH",
    };
    axios.post("/api/orders", order).then(() => setCart([]));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Food and Beverage Items</h1>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name} ({item.price}){" "}
            <button onClick={() => addToCart(item)}>Add to Cart</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <h1>Cart</h1>
      <ul>
        {cart.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name} ({item.price}){" "}
            <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(item)}>Remove</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={submitOrder}>Submit Order</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I added a closing parenthesis at the end of the component definition to match the opening parenthesis at the beginning. Now the code should work fine without any syntax errors.

Answer (score -1):

Put the ul in the map and the index could come from the map methode itself. Try this maybe :

```
items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
        <ul>
            <li key={index}>
                {item.name} 
                <button onClick={() =>removeFromCart(item)}>Remove</button>
            </li>
            <li key={index}>
                 {item.price} 
                 <button onClick={()=>removeFromCart(item)}>Remove</button>
            </li>
            
        </ul>
    )
    })
```